# Regex - extract substring with specific pattern

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a large string as shown below:

> 99/34 12/34 This text is 22.67 22/23 33/34 Second text is like is
>   22.67 55/66 45/54 Third text is like is 32.27

and so on. I am trying to form a regex expression to extract all the substrings that start with "two digits, slash, two digits, one whitespace, two digits, slash, two digits, any character any number of repetitions,one . literal and two digits" from the large string.

The regex I tried is `\d{2}/\d{2}\s{1}.*\.\d{2}`. But, this returns the a single string "99/34 12/34 This text is 22.67 22/23 33/34 Second text is like is 22.67 55/66 45/54 Third text is like is 32.27". I would like to get this extracted as

> 99/34 12/34 This text is 22.67
>
> 22/23 33/34 Second text is like is 22.67
>
> 55/66 45/54 Third text is like is 32.27

How would I do this? I am using C# (.NET 4.5)

Comment: read about lazy (or non-greedy, or reluctant) and greedy quantifiers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in the greedy `.*` it will try to match as many characters as possible while still giving a match.

You can simply modify your regex thus

```
 \d{2}/\d{2}\s.*?\d{2}\.\d{2}
```

The `?` after the `*` makes it not greedy and only consume (eat) as few characters as possible in order to find a match.

Note that I also changed `\s{1}` to `\s` as it was a single character to start with an qualifying it as exactly one does nothing but obfuscate the pattern.